# Date milliseconds JSON conversion in php

Tags: php, json, date

API connection input with JSON format has a date parameter.

Example Array

> Array ( [EventList] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [CheckDate] => /Date(1386834199000+0200)/ [ClickDate] => /Date(1386834199000+0200)/
>   [Comment] => [CommissionTotal] => 0.54 [Currency] => TRY [Date] =>
>   /Date(1386834199000+0200)/ [Description] => [EventId] => 2065404
>   [EventNb] => 1 [MediaNb] => 21 [NetworkId] => 0 [OrderId] => 805832808
>   [PaymentId] => 0 [Price] => 10.74 [ProgramId] => 209 [Status] => 0
>   [VoucherCode] => [WebsiteId] => 19887 [PartnerSubId] => 1411-151
>   [PartnerUniqueId] => 5324a1e4ce795db54a10b32314f35d59 )

All the dates are indicates as **/Date(milliseconds)/** , to convert the date I use

```
<?php
$url = 'http://login.abc.com/';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$cXML = json_decode($json, TRUE);
foreach($cXML['EventList'] as $sale)
{
    $createdmils= $sale['Date'];
    $createdmil= str_replace('/', '', $createdmils);
    $mils       = $createdmil / 1000;
    $createdDate = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $mils);
    echo $createdDate;
}
?>
```

Output is: `01-01-1970 02:00:00`

which is not correct and the system considers the date as N/A

If the date in the array could be only milliseconds without slash it would be easy to convert. How is the solution?

Comment: You're just removing the slashes, you need to get rid of the `Date` text and parenthesis as well.

Comment: Next time please format your code here more readable.

Comment: @jeroen Thanks for the solution! It is very easy actually, but I am rookie

Comment: @burzum sorry about that

Comment: @june8 So it is solved now or do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to fetch your timestamp and offset:

```php
preg_match('~(\d+)\d{3}((?:\+|-)\d+)~', $sale['Date'], $match);
print_r($match);
```

return will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1386834199000+0200
    [1] => 1386834199
    [2] => +0200
)
```

With fetched timestamp you can now format your datetime. When formating timestamp, you can also take offset into account (given one, or set your timezone), if needed so:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('@' . $match[1]);
$dt = new DateTime($dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . $match[2]);
# $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimezone("your_timezone"));
print_r($dt);
```

return will be DateTime object:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2013-12-12 07:43:19
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +02:00
)
```

which can be formated for your needs:

```php
$createdDate = dt->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```